# Config.php - Order in which modules are listed

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, sorting

Does the order in which modules are mentioned in app/etc/config.php matter for Magento 2?

I have looked closely at the code, but could not find any logic to the sorting of the modules. I know the config.php file is auto-generated.

Now assume that we manually edit the file (which you shouldn't do normally), does the order in which the modules are placed matter?

There is also a ticket on Github that relates to this, but I cannot tell what the current situation is with regards to the sequence being important or not:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8479

Answer (score 1):

**AKAIK - all the modules namespace are listed in config.php file and there order is not matter at all.**

Actually that specific modules value is matter most over here like **0 and 1**

**when you have value of 1 that means module is enabled**

**when you have value of 0 that means module is disabled**

> **apart from that - order of the module listing is not matter at all ,**
>   **but while you are editing the file you need to take care that syntax**
>   **should be a proper otherwise if you put value of first module on the**
>   **last and value of last module on the first but its value is proper**
>   **then its not matter at all.**

Answer (score 1):

modules listing is depend on `app/etc/config.php` .

The module **which is listed at first** at  `config.php`will load first.

> Yes, if you will edit `config.php` manually then the loading of the
>   modules will change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, where the ordering of modules changing was causing us problems, this is the solution we came up with: https://github.com/zero1limited/magento2-PreserveModuleOrderingInProductionMode

Answer (score 0):

The modules are loaded in the order they are mentioned in config.php as interpreted by the following quote from devdocs;

> You can check your module’s load order from the <magento_root>/app/etc/config.php file after you’ve successfully set up Magento. This file is created dynamically at run time during set up.

**Reference** : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

I also did some digging myself and found that if you mention the sequence in a module.xml the the dependent module is loaded before the current module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

According to above module.xml module A will be listed before module B in config.php and hence, loaded before the module B. Note that they may not be listed in the neighbouring nodes but the general order will be as expected always.